# drupal php code commented

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have the [Tita](http://themeforest.net/item/tita-modern-3d-drupal-theme/6367608) theme installed on my site and I can't add custom php code to my pages.

The problem is in this page:
http://www.colorser.it/#grafico
If you look at the "normal" drupal page there are no errors:
[same site]/node/52

The "page--front.tpl.php" file has a function that cycles every node, the function is:

```
<?php foreach ($pages as $key => $value) {
    print flatmetro_get_section($pages, $key);

  } ?>
```

In the template.php I looked at functions:

```
    function flatmetro_get_section($pages, $number){
          $node = isset($pages[$number]) ? $pages[$number] : '';
          if($node == ''){
            return false;
          }

          $section_name = isset($node->field_page_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) ? $node->field_page_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : '';
          return '<section class="page-section '. strtolower($section_name) .'-page page-section-'. $number .' ">' . flatmetro_get_page($pages, $number) . '</section>'; 
        }

    function flatmetro_get_page($pages, $number) {
          $node = isset($pages[$number]) ? $pages[$number] : '';

          if($node == ''){
            return false;
          }  
          $output = flatmetro_get_head_page($pages, $number) . flatmetro_get_body_page($pages, $number);

          return $output;
        }

function flatmetro_get_body_page($pages, $number){
      if(is_array($pages)){
        $node = isset($pages[$number]) ? $pages[$number] : '';
      }else{
        return FALSE;
      }
      $node = isset($pages[$number]) ? $pages[$number] : '';
      if($node == ''){
        return false;
      }
      if(isset($node) && !empty($node)){
        if(isset($node->body[$node->language])){          
          return $node->body[$node->language][0]["value"];
        }elseif(isset($node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE])){
          return $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"];
        }else{      
          return '';
        }
      }
    }
```

I checked the database data and it's not commented as I see in the output of the page.
Do you have suggestions?

Comment: After a lot of checks I see that the code is commented only when the page is rendered by the cube effect. Infact if I see the source code of the home page, php code is right.